# iPhone:How to change background brighness according to slider nob

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am using slider in my application and I want to change the background brightness as slider moves

When the nob is far left(-)  the background image is only at 70% brightness and as I move slider nob
Brightness would adjust accordingly (ie. If the nob was in the middle the image would be at 85% brightness..)

I want to clear that I am developing my app in ios 5.

then How can I set brightness..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness: yourvalue];
```

requires iOS 5.0 or later. yourvalue is a float between 0.0 and 1.0.

Set your slider value as per your need.

Comment: but how can I set range. I mean at 0 brighness would be 70% and at 100 brightness would b e 100%.

Comment: @iPhone : You can set as per your need. Try something yourself. What is your basic need ? How to set brightness or how to change its value ?

Answer (score 0):

set Alpha of image according to your slider value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `brightness` property of `UiScreen` Class use that as follows -

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness: yourvalue];`

Note: `brightness` is only available on iOS5 or later